# Command: "geth account list" while geth running

Tags: go-ethereum, accounts

When i running command
geth acoount list
i get the error - Fatal: Failed to create the protocol stack: datadir already used by another process

If i stop the geth the above command would list my accounts.

There is any way to list account while geth is running?
Why this happening?  There is anything mentioned about it in docs

Comment: last time I used this function, the accounts were stored in `datadir`  in the accounts directory

Comment: You can't have two geth instances accessing the same datadir. You could attach the second instance to the first.

Comment: @Ismael So, then i should run the command: geth attach - and access account and other stuff with javascript commands?

Comment: @illimitable That is a possible solution. Geth now supports using clef to manage accounts in a separate process from geth https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/clef/tutorial you may want to check that if it fits better with your purpose.